# Association vs Pair - Creation performance, Selection performance

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, filtering

Suppose that we

[image]

```
Ass = AssociationThread[Range[1000000], Range[1000000]^2]; // Timing
KeySelect[Ass, PrimeQ]; // Timing
Tra = Transpose[{Range[1000000], Range[1000000]^2}]; // Timing
Select[Tra, PrimeQ[#[[1]]] &]; // Timing
```

Here We create a list of mathematical pairs, and extract elements that meet a certain criteria. The criteria only concerns its 1st component. (1st component should be a prime number).

There are 2 method : `Association` vs `list of pairs`

It is much faster to create such list by `list of pairs` method.
`Association` took 0.375 seconds, whereas `Tra` took 0. seconds.

Interestingly, once such list(or association) is made, selection-job is faster in `Association`.
`Keyselect` took 0.484 seconds, whereas `Select` took 0.922 seconds.

Not so important, but to sum up,
0.375 + 0.484 < 0.+0.922
so `Association` method won in this case.

Now what you think right now and my question might be the same :

I want to create such list of pairs(equivalent) in no seconds (0. seconds like `Tra` method),   simultaneously,
I want to select elements by a criteria(that only concerns 1st component) as fast as `Keyselect`. I want to combine the advantages of both.

And in fact I've never used `Association` before. In the past, `list of pairs` was sufficient tool for me. But now there is a new aspects of `Association` - the performance.

Do you agree that when there are some filtering jobs(with criteria only concerns 1st component or only 2nd component)to do, it is recommended to create Association rather then list of pairs ?

To recap,
Q1) Can we construct list of mathematical pairs (anything equivalent)
with good performance of both creation and selection ?
Q2) If there are many selection jobs for a fixed structure of matheatica pairs, is it good to start with association rather then list of pairs?

Comment: It would be better to place a copyable code instead of an image, so others could easily play with your example. I tested your example with `RepeatedTiming` and the answers were quite different (`1.74` seconds for `Association` and `1.03` for pairs with `Pick`). `Pick[Tra, PrimeQ@Tra[[All, 1]]]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply use

```
keys = Range[1000000]; 
vals = Range[1000000]^2; 
result = Pick[vals, PrimeQ[keys]];
```

to get the best of both worlds (zero construction cost and even faster lookup). After all, `Association` is a quite heavy data structure (both in terms of storage requirements and algorithmic complexity). Build `Association`s only when

1. you need a structured dictionary or
2. you want to do random read/write access and the keys are either no positive integers or the spread of the keys is too large to use a classical array/vector for that.

Also note that most of the cost here is actually due to evaluating `PrimeQ[keys]`.

Why is `Select[Tra, PrimeQ[#[[1]]] &]` slower? There are several possible reasons.

1. `Tra` stores the data in interleaved form. So it probably does not allow any vectorization(*). In any case, this might require to pump more memory through the cache hierarchy than need.
2. `Select` is generally a bit slower than a properly setup `Pick`. Which is weird because `Pick` is more memory bound because an additional list of `True`/`False` has to be created first. But at least vectorized functions(*) can profit from this.
3. Mapping `PrimeQ[#[[1]]] &` is substantially slower than mapping `PrimeQ`.

With regard to point 3. compare this:

```
 bla = Tra[[All, {1}]];
 Map[PrimeQ[#[[1]]] &, bla]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
 Map[PrimeQ, keys]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.580334

> 0.185707

One point of this is additional indirection in the function call:

```
Map[PrimeQ[#] &, keys]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Map[PrimeQ, keys]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.284284
>
> 0.180143

But I think the major reason is that `Part` has to apply a bound check every time it is called to prevent segfaults.

(*) I don't think `PrimeQ` is vectorized, btw., albeit it is `Listable`. `Map[PrimeQ, keys]` and `PrimeQ[keys]` takes about the same time.

Comment: Thank you for very concise answer!

Comment: You're welcome!